# qemu disk showing as wrong size

Tags: windows-10, debian, virtualization, qemu

I'm trying to install debian (debian-9.9.0-amd64-netinst.iso) in qemu running on windows.  I created the disk by doing `qemu-img create -f qcow2 virtualdebian.img 30G` and `qemu-img info virtualdebian.img` returns:

```
image: virtualdebian.img
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 30G (32212254720 bytes)
disk size: 193K
cluster_size: 65536
Format specific information:
    compat: 1.1
    lazy refcounts: false7k
    refcount bits: 16
    corrupt: false
```

However, when I run qemu

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -accel hax 
  -drive file=virtualdebian.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw 
  -cdrom debian-9.9.0-amd64-netinst.iso -m 2G
```

The debian installer only shows the size of the disk to be 197kB, which it refuses to install debian on.  Where is it getting 197kB from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created the virtual disk in the QCOW2 grow-on-demand format. (The VM always sees it as full-size, but the actual file on host disk starts small and will automatically grow as the VM writes data to it.) Because the image is freshly made and doesn't contain any data yet (just the QCOW2 header), its file is currently at the minimum size.

But when attaching it, you are for some reason specifying the 'raw' format. This tells Qemu to ignore the QCOW2 header and just treat the whole file as fixed-size. (That is, if you had a 30GB file, it'd act as a 30GB disk.)

Do not mix these two modes – if you have a dynamic QCOW2 image, use `type=qcow2`.